# When moving and refactoring a file, Pycharm displays Error Cannot Move message

Tags: python, pycharm, refactoring, text-files

I tried to move a textfile to a new directory using F6 and drag and drop.
The IDE displays the following error:
Error Cannot Move

I expected to move the file successfully into the new directory. How can I move the file successfully to a new directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is related to windows 10 and 11, close Pycharm and run it as administrator and try again.